# Why was my question marked off-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to update the cell range referenced in multiple formulas at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449329/how-to-update-the-cell-range-referenced-in-multiple-formulas-at-once)

My question was marked closed due to being off-topic. I asked a very specific question about an excel issue. I received helpful responses, including one that was exactly what I was looking for. What exactly is "off-topic" here?

Comment: That question doesn't read like a specific programming problem although some argue that Macros in Excel are a programming task. I consider it to be an end-user problem. Try Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel

Comment: Additionally to what rene said, I would also say that an example on how your data looks like and what your current formulas are would serve better as a Q&A which also should help future readers. You've described your situation, but a visible example would improve that.

Comment: I just looked at your question and it's in a tag set I monitor regularly. It was closed by people expert in the tag. FWIW I would have voted the same for one of two reasons, either: 1) Because it doesn't contain sample data/information or 2) because it's really an end-user issue - all the helpful responses you got in comments are end-user solutions. Both apply. While Excel formulas *can* be on-topic on Stack Overflow, such questions should be more about how to write the formulas (which is similar to coding). Questions about which formula to use belongs more in an end-user venue :-)

Comment: Now with the answer edited into the question the post is no longer a question at all... Even if it would be on-topic on SO question with inline answer need to be closed as "Needs details or clarity" since such posts don't have anything to answer...

Comment: I've seen tons of questions like this on this site (which have previously helped me a lot), which is why I decided to use it. I didn't know the answer would be a simple formula. I also thought about providing an example but decided it wouldn't be additive. Users understood what I meant without it and were able to provide helpful answers. Why clutter the post when it's not necessary? I added the answer because the "upvote" arrow wasn't available when I was reading the answers, leaving just the flag, neither was the ability to "answer" my own question. I've since deleted it.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your question would be better suited for [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Stack Overflow is for questions specifically about programming and tools used for software development. However, the scope of superuser is much more broad; it includes questions about all computer hardware and software (not just programming  specific questions).

For more information see these articles:

- [Stack Overflow - What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [superuser - What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I don't know if I'd say their scope is "more broad" so much as just different. Programming questions are explicitly off-topic there.